# Spark Streaming Direct Stream approach with Group ID

Tags: spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I was reading the Spark Streaming kafka integration guide in the latest documentation page, which is based on Kafka 010 version.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html#creating-a-direct-stream

In that i can see one of the Kafka params is  `"group.id" -> "example"`

I thought we dont have to pass `group.id` as one of the parameter when we use DirectStream approach. I am confused on this documentation. What is the relation between group.id and Spark Streaming Direct Stream approach.

Answer (score 0):

`group.id` is a Kafka consumer configuration that is used to group a set of consumer processes into a group so that each Kafka partition can be assigned to exactly one node in the group.

Looking at the [Kafka Consumer Configuration](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kafka-0-8/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala#L89), the parameter is optional, unless we use Kafka-based offset management (which Spark Streaming doesn't use with its direct approach). So it should be an optional parameter.

Also looking at the source code of Spark [Kafka Direct DStream](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kafka-0-8/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala#L89), spark doesn't add other Kafka params that the client doesn't set. So `group.id` will default to empty string if not given.

In general, consumer group id's are needed, when you have multiple consumers (a spark streaming job, an akka application, etc.) for the same Kafka topic and you don't want all of them to fall under the same group (which they will if you don't give the group id to all of them). So I think it is a good practice to name each consumer group with its own group id. If you use operational tools around Kafka, it will also visibility about each consumer group as well, if you name them properly.

Comment: My question is specific to direct stream approach, as per my understanding `group.id` is not required in direct stream, because there is no consumer groups in direct stream approach.

Comment: Per my understanding every Kafka consumer will have to be a part of a consumer group. It is upto you to give it a specific group id. Kafka consumer groups are a fundamental part of distribution of topic partitions to consumers in the group. Each offset of a topic would be maintained per group and per partition.

Comment: But in Spark Streaming directStream approach, there is one to one mapping between Kafka partitions and RDD partitions, so there is no consumer group logic. check this http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-8-integration.html#approach-2-direct-approach-no-receivers

Comment: 1:1 mapping between Kafka partitions and RDD partitions means that Spark spawns as many tasks as there are Kafka partitions and consume them in parallel across multiple executor machines. All these tasks will have the same consumer `group id`. This ensures that each RDD partition will have the data from exactly one Kafka partition.